# What is the effective way to store over 200 emotion icons in Android application

Tags: android

I have over 200 emotion icons in my application.
And I put them in `res/drawable`.
And it really make the drawable folder so large although each icon just 1-3K.
Is there any other good methods to store these icons instead of storing them in drawable folder?
Also, I will display those icons in grid view to let users to select.
Is it good to store all in drawable folder and put them in the grid view?

Comment: Why don't you pack your emotions in single image. Like SpriteSheet. Use texturepacker application to pack your emotions.

Comment: Thank you. But can you provide more information because I never heard SpriteSheet. I just Google it and find that it is a collection of image. Your idea is great, but how to implement it and how to cut it when a user click on that icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge all your images in single bitmap. If you keep the size fixed, then you can use Bitmap.createBitmap() in a loop to generate a bitmap array.

Follow this tutorial on splitting bitmap.

[SPLITTING/DIVIDING AN IMAGE INTO SMALLER CHUNKS/PIECES IN ANDROID](http://androidattop.blogspot.com/2012/05/splitting-image-into-smaller-chunks-in.html)

[How to Split a Bitmap into Pieces in Android](http://asimkhatri90.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/how-to-split-a-bitmap-into-pieces-in-android/)